# How can I put an ordinal suffix on the end of a date?

Tags: delphi, date, formatdatetime

I'm using Delphi BDS2006 how can I format the date (01/10/2011) to look something like
`1st Oct 2011`

I tried using the 
 `ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('ddd mmm yyyy', now));`

the message I get is `Sat Oct 2011`

`ddd` gives me `Sat`and not `1st`

Similar way I want to add `st,nd,rd,th` to the Dates

Is there a built in procedure or function to do this or I have to manually check for the date and assign the suffix to it

I'm  currently using this

```
case dayof(now)mod 10 of
 1 : days:=inttostr(dayof(dob))+'st';
 2 : days:=inttostr(dayof(dob))+'nd';
 3 : days:=inttostr(dayof(dob))+'rd';
 else days:=inttostr(dayof(dob))+'th';

 end;
```

Comment: You are on the right lines but you are getting it wrong for 11 and 12. That needs special casing.

Comment: got it, it shud be 11th and 12th instead of 11st and 12nd

Comment: I realize it's just demo code, but it's far better to calculate expressions and store them rather than repeating large subexpressions.  One time, write `dayStr := inttostr(dayof(dob))`, and then use `dayStr` repeatedly inside the case, instead of repeating `inttostr(dayof(dob))`.  It doesnt improve performance since only one of those cases actually gets executed, but it's worth doing, because the DRY principle (Don't repeat yourself) leads to more readable maintainable code with fewer CopyPasta bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built in to Delphi to do that form of day. You will have to do it yourself. Like this:

```
function DayStr(const Day: Word): string;
begin
  case Day of
  1,21,31:
    Result := 'st';  
  2,22:
    Result := 'nd';  
  3,23:
    Result := 'rd';  
  else
    Result := 'th';  
  end;
  Result := IntToStr(Day)+Result;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the locale independent English version of the same. GetShortMonth is there because [`ShortMonthNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ShortMonthNames) takes the month abbreviations from the locale settings.

```
function GetOrdinalSuffix(const Value: Integer): string;
begin
  case Value of
    1, 21, 31: Result := 'st';
    2, 22: Result := 'nd';
    3, 23: Result := 'rd';
  else
    Result := 'th';
  end;
end;

function GetShortMonth(const Value: Integer): string;
begin
  case Value of
    1: Result := 'Jan';
    2: Result := 'Feb';
    3: Result := 'Mar';
    4: Result := 'Apr';
    5: Result := 'May';
    6: Result := 'Jun';
    7: Result := 'Jul';
    8: Result := 'Aug';
    9: Result := 'Sep';
    10: Result := 'Oct';
    11: Result := 'Nov';
    12: Result := 'Dec';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Day: Word;
  Month: Word;
  Year: Word;
begin
  DecodeDate(DateTimePicker1.Date, Year, Month, Day);
  ShowMessage(Format('%d%s %s %d', [Day, GetOrdinalSuffix(Day), GetShortMonth(Month), Year]));
end;
```